# How to compute z-scores for a number of right-skewed distributions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2d-array with each of its rows consisted of 25 integers among of which are a lot of 0s and hence the distribution is always right-skewed.

Ultimately, what I would like to do is to compute the z-scores on per row basis and then perform a mapping (i.e. assign an attribute to each z-score depending on its value):

```
if x < -2:
    return 'VERY_LOW'
elif x < -1:
    return 'LOW'
elif x < +1:
    return 'AVERAGE'
elif x < +2:
    return 'HIGH'
else:
    return 'VERY_HIGH'
```

My problem, however, is that the z-scores still somehow right skewed and therefore I never get LOW or VERY_LOW tags.

So, I was wondering wondering what is wrong with that, e.g. I have made a mistake in the provided bounds or in the whole idea or I just have to do something in addition (e.g. take logs).

Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

this is a sample of my data:

```
array([[  1.,   0.,   0.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   3.,
          0.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   3.,   0.,   3.,   0.,  14.,   0.,
          2.,   0.,   4.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,
          0.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   5.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   1.],
       [  1.,   1.,   0.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   2.,
          0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   3.,   0.,   3.,   0.,   5.,   0.,
          2.,   0.,   2.]])
```

this is how I compute z-scores:

```
z_scores = st.mstats.zscore(data, axis=1, ddof=1)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of array values you have? Also how are you currently calculating the standard score?

Comment: please have a look on my edit if you don't mind

Comment: The standard deviation (`[ 2.9,  1.1,  1.4]`) is just fairly large for this example data. Take into account the means (`[ 1.5,  0.5,  1.1]`) and you'd need values of less than `[-4.5, -1.6, -2.5]` in those rows. The coding is correct, it's just that your dataset won't necessarily be comparable to a normally distributed variable.